# find Combinations of all sets - set cover?

Tags: java, algorithm

Can someone please share a program in java which does the following.
if given the following sets as inputs,

```
a={1,2,3,8,9,10}
b={1,2,3,4,5}
c={4,5,7}
d={5,6,7}
e={6,7,8,9,10}
```

and

```
U={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

the program will find all the combinations of the set and find out the minimum number of sets that together has all the elements of U.

In the above example, the minimum number is 2. set b and e together covers all of U.
So basically, it is a set covering problem. In the Set Covering problem, we are given a universe U, such that `|U|=n`, and sets `S1,……,Sk` are subsets of U. A set cover is a collection C of some of the sets from `S1,……,Sk` whose union is the entire universe U. Additionally, we must minimize the cost of the sets.

Comment: No it is not.  I wrote a program that uses greedy alg. to find the min-cover. The greedy does not always come up with the minimum number of sets. If I had a program that finds the optimal result (does not have to be efficient) then I would be able to compare the results.

Comment: How many sets does it need to be good for? In your example there are only five sets, and hence only 32 possibilities to test. So test them all.

Comment: for different number of sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to test increasing sizes of combinations, like so

```
interface Filter<T> {
    boolean matches(T t);
}
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Integer[][] arrayOfSets = {
            {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {4, 5, 7},
            {5, 6, 7},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    };
    Integer[] solution = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    List<Set<Integer>> listOfSets = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    for (Integer[] array : arrayOfSets)
        listOfSets.add(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array)));
    final Set<Integer> solutionSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(solution));

    Filter<Set<Set<Integer>>> filter = new Filter<Set<Set<Integer>>>() {
        public boolean matches(Set<Set<Integer>> integers) {
            Set<Integer> union = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
            for (Set<Integer> ints : integers)
                union.addAll(ints);
            return union.equals(solutionSet);
        }
    };

    Set<Set<Integer>> firstSolution = shortestCombination(filter, listOfSets);
    System.out.println("The shortest combination was "+firstSolution);
}

private static <T> Set<T> shortestCombination(Filter<Set<T>> filter, List<T> listOfSets) {
    final int size = listOfSets.size();
    if (size > 20) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many combinations");
    int combinations = 1 << size;
    List<Set<T>> possibleSolutions = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
    for(int l = 0;l<combinations;l++) {
        Set<T> combination = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            if (((l >> j) & 1) != 0)
                combination.add(listOfSets.get(j));
        }
        possibleSolutions.add(combination);
    }
    // the possible solutions in order of size.
    Collections.sort(possibleSolutions, new Comparator<Set<T>>() {
        public int compare(Set<T> o1, Set<T> o2) {
            return o1.size()-o2.size();
        }
    });
    for (Set<T> possibleSolution : possibleSolutions) {
        if (filter.matches(possibleSolution))
            return possibleSolution;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Prints

```
The shortest combination was [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solutions is awesome.I tried with different sizes/number of sets, and it gave me the correct solution. If we wanted to have the user enter the elements of the set, how would you do it? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Are you using a console or a gui? If you are using a console, you need to read the numbers in a loop, Search for Scanner examples.

Comment: I'm using console (Scanner class to read input from the console).What if the user wanted different numbers of sets, how would you do that? Can you please show me the modified code. I'm sorry I have no idea how to accept your answer. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I was looking over your solution again. why are you printing message if there are more than 20 combinations?

Comment: Peter, do you have an approach to this that minimises weights too? Each of my subsets has a weight. I want to find the set of subsets that gives full coverage but has minimum max weight. Minimum average weight will break ties when max weight is equal.

Comment: @SteveW I suggest you sort the sets after building them or you could compare them as you generate them only retaining the minimum rather than a set.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an optimal solution and since [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) is NP-complete, just generate all possible combinations by brute force. For an input of `n` sets, there will be `2^n - 1` possible combinations. You can generate each combination in turn as follows:

```
let the input sets be S1, S2, ..., Sn
let min = { S1, S2, ..., Sn } // initially assume all sets are required
for i = 1, 2, ..., 2^n - 2
  let X = {}
  represent i as a binary number containing n bits
  for each bit j that is set to 1, include set Sj in X
  if X covers all sets and #X < #min
    update min = X
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. But if you are still interested in this, you can get approximate solutions to set cover using the Rajagopalan-Vazirani algorithm: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=299880. This will give you answers that are at most a factor 2 away from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Let `I` represents set of elements included so far.

1. Initialize `I = {}`
2. Do following while `I` is not same as `U`

   - a) Find the set `Si` in `{S1, S2, ... Sm}` whose cost effectiveness is smallest.
   - b) Add elements of above picked `Si` to `I`, i.e.,  `I = I U Si`.