# How to group route of journey (Set cover problem)

Tags: algorithm, set-cover

I have this issue need to solve:

**Input**:

- List of route between city, all route will start from same origin
- Set of all city

**Output**:

- Group of path that can visit all city, if not found then return group cover the most of city with minimum of route.

## **Example**:

### Testcase 1:

#### Input

- Route List:

  1.`Newyork -> Washington -> Los Angeles -> Chicago` 
  2.`Newyork -> Houston -> Alaska` 
  3.`Newyork -> Dallas`
  4.`Newyork -> Houston -> Washington -> Chicago -> Los Angeles -> Alaska`
  5.`Newyork -> Alaska`
  6.`Newyork -> Chicago`
  7.`Newyork -> Los Angeles`
- City: `Newyork, Washington, Los Angeles, Chicago, Alaska, Dallas, Houston`

#### Output:

1.`Newyork -> Houston -> Washington -> Chicago -> Los Angeles -> Alaska`
2.`Newyork -> Dallas`

This is best group because with only 2 route it can visit all given cities

### Testcase 2:

#### Input

- Route List:

  1.`Newyork -> Washington -> Los Angeles -> Chicago` 
  2.`Newyork -> Houston -> Alaska` 
  3.`Newyork -> Dallas`
  4.`Newyork -> Alaska`
  5.`Newyork -> Chicago`
  6.`Newyork -> Los Angeles`
- City: `Newyork, Washington, Los Angeles, Chicago, Alaska, Dallas, Houston`

#### Output:

1.`Newyork -> Washington -> Los Angeles -> Chicago`
2.`Newyork -> Houston -> Alaska`
3.`Newyork -> Dallas`

This is best group because with 3 routes it can visit all given cities

### Testcase 3:

#### Input

- Route List:

  2.`Newyork -> Houston -> Alaska` 
  3.`Newyork -> Dallas`
  4.`Newyork -> Alaska`
  5.`Newyork -> Chicago`
  6.`Newyork -> Los Angeles`
- City: `Newyork, Washington, Los Angeles, Chicago, Alaska, Dallas, Houston`

#### Output:

1.`Newyork -> Houston -> Alaska`
2.`Newyork -> Chicago`
3.`Newyork -> Dallas`
4.`Newyork -> Los Angeles`

This is best group because with 4 routes it can visit 6/7 cities (except `Washington`)

#### implementation

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<List<String>> allRoutes = new ArrayList<>();
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Houston","Alaska"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Dallas"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Houston","Washington","Chicago","Los Angeles","Alaska"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Alaska"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Chicago"));
    allRoutes.add(List.of("Newyork","Los Angeles"));
    Set<String> cities = new HashSet<>(List.of("Newyork","Houston","Washington","Chicago","Los Angeles","Alaska"));

    List<List<String>> result = findBestRoute(allRoutes, cities);
    //expected allPaths:
    //`Newyork -> Houston -> Washington -> Chicago -> Los Angeles -> Alaska`\
    //`Newyork -> Dallas`

  }

private static void findBestRoute(List<List<String>> allRoutes, Set<String> cities){
   //implementation
}
```

So any advice for algorithm i can use?

Comment: It's not Knapsack, it's [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: thanks @Olivier look like i can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287302/find-combinations-of-all-sets-set-cover
just wonder do we have library for it or not